Giving a label a border in custom tkinter
I am using customtkinter for a project I am working on in Python.
I would like to make a border around the labels I am using for the camera. Currently, here is the code for my label.
main_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(root, height=400, width=1000)
main_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky='EW')
main_frame.grid_propagate(False)

left_cap_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=main_frame, text="left_cap_label")
left_cap_label.place(relx=.25, rely=.5, anchor="center")

right_cap_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=main_frame, text="right_cap_label")
right_cap_label.place(relx=.75, rely=.5, anchor="center")

I would like to make the left_cap_label and right_cap_label have borders around them, preferably in white. Is there any way to do this? I know in regular tkinter you can use borderwith, but I am not sure if there is an alternative in custom tkinter. Thank you!
I had a look at the documentation for a border argument under the CTkLabel, but I couldn'tf find any.

I know you can do this with a CTkButton (it has the border_width argument) but i didn't find any way to do it with a label. You could maybe use a modified button (remove interaction when mouse is on the button, set fg_color to transparent...) to solve your issue.
